# Not Found Problem (The requested resource [/CustomerManager/] is not available)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I've been dealing for a long time but I couldn't show the webpage.I've been dealing for hours, but I couldn't figure it out. I keep getting this error. Directory works when you open WebContent but does not print messages. I need help

My Problem;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmM3Q.jpg)

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Custom Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
        <h1>asdasdas</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
<artifactId>CustomerManager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.20</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>





<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>13</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

CustomerController

```
package net.codejava.customer;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello From Spring MVC");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer

```
package net.codejava.customer.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer  implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {


        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext= new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher= servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfig

```
package net.codejava.customer.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.codejava")
public class WebMvcConfig {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved: Right Click CustomerManager folder- properties- Java Build Path - Librarires - JRE System Librraries[JavaSe-13]- edit- Change JavaSe-13 to JavaSe-9 -finish -apply.

And project is working. But why dont working JavaSe 13

Answer (score 0):

quick solution:
if you are running from IDE(eclipse or intellij), open file /.settings 
file. see the value for the tag: `<property name="context-root" value=`
take that value which is the root element for your URLs.
ex: if it's "abc", then you can use `http://localhost:8082/abc/`
if the value is something else, use that value.

Other option is to check the value under `server.xml` under your tomcat servers and look at the tag `<Context docBase="abc" path="/abc"`
take value of path and use in your URL. ex: `http://localhost:8082/abc/`

Comment: I dont understand this, how i do? I get this error in all the examples, I'm unable to any project.

Comment: let me know the IDE where you are running your application.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) Thank you in advance for your interest

Comment: Go to your project location on your system, ex: in windows it could be c:\projects\spring-demo. Under the project location, you will have ".settings" file, open it and get find out the element: ```"<property name="context-root" value="```. let me know what is the value. This is one thing. and another is: under your server (I assume it's tomcat) folder in eclipse, open the server.xml and go to the line ```<Context docBase="abc" path="/abc"```. show us that line.

Comment: org.eclipse.wst.common.component in this folder  <property name="context-root" value="AlienInformation"/>

Comment: And in Eclipse(Tomcat) server.xml DOCBASE      <Context docBase="JettyTestProject" path="/JettyTestProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JettyTestProject"/><Context docBase="Customer" path="/Customer" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Customer"/><Context docBase="CustomerManager" path="/CustomerManager" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CustomerManager"/><Context docBase="AlienInformation" path="/AlienInformation" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:AlienInformation"/></Host>

Comment: since you have ```/CustomerManager``` in the server.xml it should work. not sure what is the real issue. you can play around these like removing/cleaning other applications from server which you are not being used. Also you can try just by keeping "/CustomerManager" application and removing all other applications from server.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried these a lot, but there is no solution. My problem is continue at all project.